# Pet's behavior - Asking for food or thanking for food?

Tags: dogs, behavior, eating

We have quite a few kittens at our place and any time any neighbor pets come my parents give them food.
There are 2 dogs which we neighbor owns and those two dogs are like the street guards and bark at any unknown person/bike/car that goes through that area, so the owners refused to feed the dogs as other started complaining about the barking and the dogs chasing the vehicles. 
However my parents continued to feed them.

Recently about 3-4 weeks backs one of the dog started the behavior shown in the image below

[image]

Every time our car comes close the gate, one of the dog will come running towards us the car with anything that it can pick up like leaves, sticks.

Is this behavior asking for food or kind of a way saying thank you (or exchange for food)?

(We feed them in the morning and the night only)

Comment: Looks a bit like the behavior of one of our dogs. If he really, really wants something (like dried chicken), he'd pick up some toy or anything else he can find and drop it on a lap, more or less trading. Might be projection into something coincidentally but he does it a bit too regular for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a few dogs do this as a way of saying hello, I'm happy to see you - I want to give you something because I love you! Some highly people friendly dogs will do this to strangers as well, they love everybody.

That being said, they probably do want food too :)

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of understanding dog behavior is to remember:

#### Dogs are pack animals!

Different from humans, they filter every interaction, every event through the lens of the pack. Some *pack rules* you should familiarize yourself with are as follows:

A subset of the rules of the pack:

1. The pack must have a strong **alpha** in order for the pack to be strong.
2. The pack must be strong in order for the dog to feel safe and secure.
3. The identity of the alpha is not fixed, but constantly changing and up for challenge at any time.
4. The dog is, therefore, always trying to identify the alpha.
5. He who controls the food is the first candidate for being the alpha. But not necessarily so if other alpha behaviors do not follow.

In this case, the dog considers his food source (your parents) as a potential alpha *candidate*. The act of bringing you leaves and such is a proxy for bringing you food (a *kill*, which the dog does not have and to which the pack alpha would be entitled).